# Webkit vs Chromium vs Quantum loops

Tags: javascript, loops, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Benchmark (https://jsben.ch/IWqVX) on various browser engines

Safari [Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi1Ve.png)

Chrome [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lro13.png)

Firefox [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV7ax.png)

has revealed different results when using "for of" and "for in" loops.

Is there any way in JavaScript to determine which loops should be used to optimize an app for better performance?

The benchmark results were anticipated to provide insights into optimizing app performance.

Comment: stop worrying about micro-optimisation - unless you really are dealing with loops of 10's of millions of iterations

Comment: Use the one that makes sense _for your code_, not _for the engine_. The differences will be negligible for such core JS features, and your stuff will run in different browsers with different optmisations and should run eqaully fine with minor speed boosts here and speed losses there. If you were programming in C, fine, but JS? Don't focus on this.

Comment: I have a high-load SPA, so it would make sense for me to optimize its performance by choosing efficient loops.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.